# Alfresco moving document

Tags: listener, alfresco, execution

I have an execution listener script, that moves a file during the workflow to another folder, from `In` folder to `Execut`.

When I'm starting workflow from User files it works good, but from document library in site it doesn't work, showing  `error org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 05190025 Failed to execute supplied script: Destination Node is a mandatory parameter`

The folder tree in document library is the same.

```
var dest = companyhome.childByNamePath("Execut");
    for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++){
        bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
    }
```

### What is the problem?

i'm understood what the problem is, this code `companyhome.childByNamePath("Execut");` defines path to users folder  and than  moves documents from document library folders to user files folder. Need to define correct destination folder path in document library.
How to do it?

---

document moves from doc library to users folder, but I need that it moves to folder in document library
and I don't know how to define path.
I'm trying `companyhome.childByNamePath("site/main/documentLibrary/Execut");`
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your process defination with below code.

```
var dest = companyhome.childByNamePath("Sites/main/documentLibrary/Execut");
for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++)
{
        bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
}
```

You are using wrong path.Path for site is  **Sites/main/documentLibrary/Execut**
and not **site/main/documentLibrary/Execut**